# Stop GitKraken asking for login credentials

Tags: tfs, gitkraken

GitKraken has successfully cloned a repository hosted on Team Foundation Server, but on subsequent fetch and push it asks for login information. Even when provided it will ask again, offering no error or explanation. "Remember me" is checked.

Everything works perfectly fine using the cmd.

Note that the issue occurs on a virtual machine. I have tested interacting with the repository on my physical machine using GitKraken - no problem there. However, I have previously experienced the same type of problem with other projects on my physical machine. Seems GitKraken sometimes has problems with TFS, but not sure.

I have tried reinstalling GitKraken, but it didn't resolve the issue. Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Edit 2018-01-24 as per @Cece Dongs comment**

- I am using GitKraken 3.3.3 - recently upgraded, but issue still occurs.
- TFS is version 15.117.26714.0 and using the web portal does not give me problems. I login once like normally.

When cloning a GitHub repo everything is working properly. However, when attempting to clone a TFS repo from Visual Studio I get an unauthorized error. (TF30063). I assume it could be related to the Active Directory settings not set up properly because of the Hyper-V setup I am using. Will investigate further and provide more details here.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Which version of GitKraken are you using? If you access TFS from web portal, would you get frequent logging request? You could do some more tests here: Clone a repo hosted other system, like GitHub or VSTS. 2. Clone a repo hosted on TFS from other client tool, like VS, to see how's the result.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I edited my question with the information you requested.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT - problem solved. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After using *\domain\username* instead of just *username* as login credentials to TFS everything is working.

Using only the username will work on my physical machine as that machine is recognized on the domain, but as the virtual machine is not, the domain is required.

Comment: I used username@domain